# How to change date format of a jQuery Date Picker plugin (Jonathan Leighton Input Date)

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am using Jonathan Leighton's Date Picker Plugin (Input Date)
URl : http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input

The problem is, The selected date is in the format "16 Aug 2010"

I want it to be in the format of "2010-08-16" i..e yyyy-mm-dd

Also, is it possible to include timings as well.. i..e set both date and time using this plugin??

Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very page you linked to has an example how to format the date in YYYY-MM-DD:

http://jonathanleighton.com/projects/date-input#date-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [jQuery UI's datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). It has more options (also date format) and callbacks. 
This datepicker has something like timepicker plugin too: http://blog.w3visions.com/2009/04/date-time-picker-with-jquery-ui-datepicker/

Comment: Though the mentioned plugins are really cooool, i wanted to know how i can implement the needed date format for this plugin

Comment: Start to use and understand what documentation says. There "options" tab where all available options are described. What you need is `dateFormat` option. For example: `$("selector").datepicker({dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});`